# Convergence of series of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $\phi \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be a function such that $\phi(x), \phi'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

I want to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\mathbb R \cos(nx) \phi(x) \ dx = 0$$

Doing it by parts, I get $\int_\mathbb R \cos(nx) \phi(x) \ dx  = - \int_\mathbb R \frac 1n \sin (nx) \phi'(x) \ dx$

It is easy to see that $\frac 1n \sin (nx) \phi'(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$.
It is difficult though to find a function that dominates it, so I can't apply the lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

But $$\sup \left|\frac 1n \sin (nx) \phi'(x)\right| \le \frac{\sup | \phi'(x)| } n \to 0$$ so the functions converges uniformily to $0$ and I can bring the limit inside the integral sign and it is proven

Is it a correct proof of this fact?

P.S. Actually $\phi(x)$ are supposed to be  in the Schwartz space $\mathcal S$, but I believe that the it is still true with the limited assumptions. Also it is easier to understand this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is not correct. It would work if $\phi'$ were integrable.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Where did it go wrong and there would I use the hypothesis of integrability on $\phi'$?

Comment: The integral of $\phi'$ may be $\infty$. $1/n$ converges uniformly to $0$, but $\int_\mathbb{R}1/n$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I first need to make sure that the integral converges and then I can use uniform convergence. Of course if $\phi \in \mathcal S$ then $\phi'$ is integrable and the proof works. Thank you :-)